# How does threading.Lock actually work? (with multiple scenarios)

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

I have looked online and done some searching through stackoverflow and the internet about locks and I just seem to get a general understanding that when a lock is active another thread cannot use it??

I have multiple shared objects which are being read/written constantly throughout the script and I'm still not 100% sure how the locking function really works? When do you need to use it, when do you not need to use it and is it worth creating individual locks for each shared variable/object?

When a thread calls a lock does that mean other threads will only pause at that particular part of the script where the lock was originally called or does it somehow acknowledge to stop reading/writing any variables within the acquire/release function call throughout the entire script?

If I have multiple locks specifically for each shared variable/object and one lock function is called, does this effect the rest of the locks too?

I think to summerise, I'm struggling to understand the "in-depth" version of locking, only being able to find a general overview amongst previous explanations online.